# convex set containing origin which is not balanced in TVS

Tags: functional-analysis

In topological vector space, intuitively a balanced set is a set which doesn't have a hole. Suppose $V$ is a convex set containing origin, can anyone give a counterexample which is not balanced?

Comment: The interval $(-1,2)$ is an example in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{C}$, take a square with the origin as center.

Comment: (or more generally, take any convex set containing $0$ that is *not* a disc)